# Download power BI dashboard programmatically

Tags: vb.net, ssis, powerbi

I am trying to write a VB code to export Power BI dashboard from PowerBI server to local path using script task in SSIS using HTTP Connection Manager. A 5KB file is getting generated but not able to open it. Could anyone help me to fix this up.

```
Dim HttpCon As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("ReportServer")
    Dim ClientCon As HttpClientConnection = New HttpClientConnection(HttpCon.AcquireConnection(Nothing))
    Dim ReportFileName As String = "C:\localpath\Warranty.pdf"
    ClientCon.ServerURL = "http://powerbidev.abc.com/Reports/powerbi/FolderName/&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rc:Toolbar=False"
    ClientCon.DownloadFile(ReportFileName, True)
```

Comment: "Assist" Or "do that for me"? **Assisiting** assumes you´ve tried something yourself and are stuck at some specific point. So please provide what you´ve tried.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far and explain what your question is in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Power BI API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exportreport) (link to request you need) to accomplish it.
There should be a programmatic authnetication first, but it is a whole new topic.
Also, there are [nu-get package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/powerbi-embedded?view=azure-dotnet) to do it, but you will got problems with adding additional ddls to Script task, when deploying package to server.